# How to resize image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, resize-image

I often see some websites using the below code to resize image size.

```
?w=250
?w=150
?w=75 
?w=50
```

Sample:

```
http://domain.com/customthumb/2013/08/07/72/getty380.jpg?w=250
http://domain.com/customthumb/2013/08/07/72/getty380.jpg?w=150
http://domain.com/customthumb/2013/08/07/72/getty380.jpg?w=75
http://domain.com/customthumb/2013/08/07/72/getty380.jpg?w=50
```

I already search in Google, but I can't find the solution.

Do you know how to do it in PHP?

---

This is the demo:

Original size don't using "**?w=75**" or other size:
_http://images.detik.com/customthumb/2013/08/09/722/uang4depan.jpg

**width 75px** : _http://images.detik.com/customthumb/2013/08/09/722/uang4depan.jpg?w=75

**width 100px** : _http://images.detik.com/customthumb/2013/08/09/722/uang4depan.jpg?w=100

**width 110px** : _http://images.detik.com/customthumb/2013/08/09/722/uang4depan.jpg?w=110

**width 150px** : _http://images.detik.com/customthumb/2013/08/09/722/uang4depan.jpg?w=150

**Note**: remove underscore "_" in front of URL.

Comment: `I already search in Google, but i can't find the solution.` whats that means? [How to resize image in PHP](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+resize+image+in+PHP&oq=How+to+resize+image+in+PHP&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i60j69i62l2.820j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Timthumb will create thumbnails with given width or height. For example http://test.com/timthumb.php?src=/img/bigImage.jpg&w=120&h=120. It will create a new jpg under cache folder at first call and use it at calls afterwards. You can achieve your examples with url rewrite and timthumb, Give this a shot, it has some other useful functionality too, https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what those URLS are for, but many PHP users use the [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) functions to manipulate images.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, considering what's your output.
First of all, HTML can do this so if you use

```
print "&lt;img src='...whatever...' width='$x'&gt;"
```

this will do the trick. Now if you're writing with a header like image/jpg, which means you're being called from an IMG tag and your script returns the image itself - well, use GD library and **imagecopyresampled()**. But that's a thing I'll explain in detail only if you really need it.

Comment: I think i need that, can you explain, please!